# Mouse Right Click Keyboard Shortcut in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In most Windows applications, I am able to replicate the right mouse button click using the combo Shift + F10.  Shift + F10 is mapped as a shortcut to debug my current file in PHPStorm.  I've looked around the mapping section in settings but wasn't able to find a way to restore this combo so that it mimics a right mouse click.  Is this possible in PHPStorm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The action you need is called **Show Context Menu** and located under **Other** branch in **Settings | Keymap**

[image]

**P.S.**
Screenshot above shows <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> shortcut already assigned to it.

**P.P.S.**
It is for v6, but I assume it will work in v5 as well.